# Python Fabric No hosts found. Please specify with the exists function

Tags: python, fabric

I am currently trying to run a small fabric script. I am having the following message : "No hosts found. Please specify ..." when running the exists fabric function.

I have defined my hosts like that :

```
env.roledefs.update({
            'app' : [
                'my_host',
            ],
        })
```

Then I am calling this function :

```
@roles("app")
def update_django():
    django_dir = ...
    if exists(django_dir):
```

I can't figure out why he is asking for the host ... It should be defined thanks to the @roles decorator.

Answer (score 0):

does it work when you use the hosts decorator?

```
@hosts("my_hostname")
def update_django():
    django_dir = ...
    if exists(django_dir):
```

Did you remember all the imports?

```
from fabric.api import env, hosts, roles, run
```

Comment: It doesn't I am afraid.

Comment: can you show me what your call to fabric is? I.e. what is under the if exists():

Comment: Oh actually it is my fault. My fabric version doesn't have this decorator. Sorry for this.